# Kubernetes: spec.clusterIP: invalid value?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, skydns

Whether prompt, What linked in kubernetes this message:

```
The Service "skudns" is invalid:spec.clusterIP: invalid value '': the provided range does not match the current range
```

At that that `DNS_SERVICE_IP = 10.3.0.10`, and `SERVICE_IP_RANGE = 10.3.0.0/16`

My ip-address:

```
K8S_SERVICE_IP: 10.3.0.1
MASTER_HOST: 192.168.0.139
ETCD_ENDPOINT=ETCD_CLUSTER=http://192.169.0.139:2379,http://192.168.0.107:2379
POD_NETWORK: 10.2.0.0/16
SERVICE_IP_RANGE: 10.3.0.0/24
DNS_SERVICE_IP: 10.3.0.10
ADVERTISE_IP: 192.168.0.139
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/16` [means a subnet mask](http://doc.m0n0.ch/quickstartpc/intro-CIDR.html) of 255.255.0.0 (instead of 255.255.255.0 with `/24`)

The error message comes from [`pkg/registry/service/ipallocator/allocator_test.go#L196-L198`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b9cfab87e33ea649bdd13a1bd243c502d76e5d22/pkg/registry/service/ipallocator/allocator_test.go#L196-L198)

```go
if !network.IP.Equal(cidr.IP) || network.Mask.String() != cidr.Mask.String() {
    t.Fatalf("mismatched networks: %s : %s", network, cidr)
}
```

It might be possible the host network mask (seen in `ipconfig` if the host is Windows, or [`ifconfig` as in this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Juniper/contrail-kubernetes/vrouter-manifest/cluster/provision_minion.sh)) might be different from the cidr mask used by kubernetes.
Try with `/24` just for testing.
See also [issue 5 (Network comportment)](https://github.com/tdeheurles/homecores/issues/5#issue-109825651)

In the end, the [OP batazor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3197412/batazor) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173253/kubernetes-spec-clusterip-invalid-value/34173688#comment56136110_34173688) an issue on Kubernetes side:

> kubernetes updated from version 1.0.3 to 1.0.6 and got `docker0` mask to 255.255.255.0 This is some sort of magic.

Comment: First I have tried `/ 24`, but this was an error, and I tried to change to `/ 16`. It did not help.

Masks are the same, so the output log: https://gist.github.com/batazor/02f8e9bd737a2789bfff

Comment: @batazor so it is confirmed then: the flannel.1 10.0.x.x network created by kubernetes has a different mask (/16) than your host network (/24)

Comment: I updated flannel.1 mask: https://gist.github.com/batazor/b877f61439f606775c68

Unfortunately the problem persists :-(

Comment: @batazor Make sense, since your docker0 network mask has changed again: 255.255.255.128 (mask /25 instead of /24). You need /24 for both docker0 and flannel.1

Comment: I update it? 
`POD_NETWORK: 10.2.0.0/16 -> 10.2.0.0/24`
`docker.service ([Network] Address: 10.2.48.0/24)`

Comment: @batazor I agree, you updated it and that part worked: your `flannel.1` network does have the right mask /24. But your host `docker0` network, for some reason, does not (/25 instead of /24).

Comment: During the night the problem was solved, kubernetes updated from version 1.0.3 to 1.0.6 and got dockre0 mask 255.255.255.0 This is some sort of magic ...

Comment: @batazor Great. I have included that in the answer for more visibility.